# iOS dev license

Tags: developer-program

Sorry my googlefu isn't helping me on this.
When I pay the $100 to Apple for a dev license, do I

- get the ability to submit to iOS and Mac app stores
  or
- there is a separate $100 I have to spend on both app stores?

I ask because my developer account says "iOS developer program - expired", and I see no option to sign up for the mac app store.

TIA

Comment: You said, "Sorry my googlefu isn't helping me on this.", well a good place to start is at the source: [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)

Comment: I did look at the apple dev program, unfortunately my account says "iOS dev program", not just "dev program", so I came here for a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Developer program allows individuals or companies to develop software for all devices. This means that paying the $99USD yearly membership fee, enables you (the account holder or company) to develop, distribute and maintain apps for both iOS as well as macOS devices and publish them to their respective app store.

**No**, to the best of my knowledge a separate fee does not exist.